# Assuming an array of 'bool', can 'a[n] == (-1)' ever be true?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have some code where I have two bool arrays `a[]` and `b[]`, same size `N`.

`it` is an iterator pointing to an index of `a`, possibly between `0` to `N-1`

```
if( (a[*it] == 1 && index>*it) ||
    (a[index]==b[index] && a[index]==-1 && index!=0))
{
      final = !final;
}
```

Accourding to me, the second part of the if condition `|| (a[index]==b[index] && a[index]==-1 && index!=0)` can never be true, because `a[index]` will not be equal to `-1` for any `index` , it would be either `1` or `0`. .. so I thought I can remove that part, however the result changes, for some particular conditions (I dont know the conditions, it's an online judge type site and I dont know what their testcases are).

I added another test condition just before this `if` part in my program,

```
if(a[index]==-1){
cout<<"its True";
}
```

but "its True" was never printed.

Why could this happen?

Edit :
Adding actual code, the purpose of program is to handle queries of type

`set_a INDEX VALUE`

`set_b INDEX VALUE`

which sets corresponding index(0..n-1) to value(0 or 1)
and

`get_c index`
which prints out `c[index]` where C=A+B

note, `INDEX` is from LSB side, i am storing LSB of A and B in MSB of the array `a` and `b`

Code :

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int n, q;
  char c;
  bool a[100005] = {0}, b[100005] = {0};
  VanEmdeBoasTree equals;
  cin>>n;
  cin>>q;

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>c;
    if(c=='1')
      a[n-i-1] = true;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>c;
    if(c=='1')
      b[n-i-1] = true;
    if(a[n-i-1] == b[n-i-1]){
      equals.insert(n-i-1);
    }
  }

  string query;
  int index, val, lastval;
  for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
    cin>>query;
    cin>>index;
    if(query[4] == 'a'){
      cin>>val;
      if(a[index] != val){
        a[index] = val;
        if(val == b[index]){
          equals.insert(index);
        }else{
          equals.erase(index);
        }
      }
    }else if(query[4] == 'b'){
      cin>>val;
      if(b[index] != val){
        b[index] = val;
        if(a[index] == val){
          equals.insert(index);
        }else{
          equals.erase(index);
        }
      }
    }else if(query[4] == 'c'){
      int final = 0;
      if(index >n-1){
        if(equals.size() > 0){
          int last = (*(equals.predecessor(n+1)));
          if(a[last] == 1){
            final = 1;
          }
        }
      }else{

        if(equals.size() > 0 && index>0){
          VanEmdeBoasTree::const_iterator it = equals.predecessor(index);
          final = (a[index] + b[index])%2;
          if( (a[*it] == 1 && index>*it) || (a[index]==b[index] && a[index]==-1 && index!=0)){
            final = !final;
          }

        }else{
          final = (a[index] + b[index])%2;
        }

      }
      cout<<final;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `a` is `bool[]` then `a[index]==-1` looks highly suspicious.

Comment: @spraff yeah, it was actually a Typo, i accedently submitted the solution with this typo, and this led to `correct answer for test case #6` whatever else i do, best i get is `correct till #5` :-/

Comment: Since the boolean value for true is "not 0", -1 does count.  Some implementations use -1 as a boolean value (see VARIANT_TRUE in COM) since it is all-bits-set as opposed to 0's all-bits-cleared.  Then again, if it's actually a "bool", then the code is not checking what it thinks it's checking.

Comment: Iterators are not pointers to indices, but rather pointers into the array (or other data structure) itself. (In other words, where is the use for a pointer to an indices as opposed to just that indices?)

Comment: @Xeo `it` is the result of a `find` functionof a vEB tree, so *it contains the found value if its not ==`vEBtree.end()`

Answer (score 5):

If `a` is indeed a `bool` array, then unless you go out of bounds `a[i]==-1` will always yield `false`. There is just no question in that. On the other hand, if you ***do*** go out of bounds, then the behavior is ***undefined*** meaning that everything can happen, including a boolean value evaluating to `-1`.

Also, there's a possibility that `a` is a `BOOL` array rather than `bool`. `BOOL` could be `typedef`'d or `#define`d as `int`.

***Update:*** Since the OP maintains that the array is of type `bool` and there is absolutely no chance of overflow (let me pretend for a while that I believe him), then I should note that if a program contains a construct which leads to undefined behavior, then the behavior of the ***whole*** program is undefined, even prior to reaching the construct that exhibits undefined behavior. So, even if the `a` array is always indexed correctly, but some other unrelated array isn't, then it's still possible that you get garbage in `a`. Never expect any sort of consistency in a program with undefined behavior.

Comment: `index` never goes out of bounds, its always {0, n-1} inclusive, and the array indeed are `bool` and not `BOOL`

Comment: i added my whole code, can you point out the `construct which leads to undefined behavior` ? secondly, you can check/verify that INDEX would never go out of bounds.

Comment: @Phoenix: I looked at your code and no, I cannot point to a construct which leads to undefined behavior. The only suspicious part is when you input the index and don't check its value, but I guess that the problem statement clearly states that it will not be out of bounds. Is it true? Are you sure that the index is 0-based in the input? Maybe there is undefined behavior in your class? in ***any*** case, a boolean value will ***never*** be equal to `-1` unless the behavior of the program is undefined

Comment: yes, they wont give illegal `INDEX` values in any case. the Tree implementation is located here : http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=van-emde-boas-tree ... and yes the INDEX is 0 based.

Comment: @Phoenix: I see in the documentation that "predecessor returns an iterator to the first element in the tree whose key is strictly less than the specified value (or end() if one does not exist)". If it actually returned end(), you'd get UB(because you dereference it). How sure are you that it will always find what you ask it to find and not return end()? – Armen Tsirunyan 25 secs ago edit

Comment: yes, i noticed that, and i added that in the IF condition as well, how ever that didn't help, the submissions here is very old one and i have submitted more after this, with the `it!=equals.end()` check, however this is the only submission which could get to `passed testcase #6`, other go up to only `passed testcase #5`

Comment: @Phoenix: Then I give up. Sorry for not being able to help. In any case, you could just re-write the code from scratch. That helps a lot of times

Comment: Thanks for the effort, i already wasted 4 days in this now :-/

Comment: If vEB tree was to contain `a construct which leads to undefined behavior` is there some way i can detect it/find it ... any procedure so this ?

Comment: @Phoenix: None that I am aware of except for looking at the code

Comment: its the latter, 100%, i dont know if keeping it not answered should be the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that sometimes one of `index` or '*it' is not actually in range. How a bool is stored is rather implementation dependant, but it you run off the end of the array, then it'd be quite possible to return values other than 0 or 1.

Incidentally, comparing a[*it] with 1 is not a good thing if a is a bool array. it should be just tested thus:

```
   if (a[*it] && something)
```

Comment: the concerned part is the one with `index` in the if condition, as when i remove it(everything else remains the same), some test case fails, so all i can think of is that somehow `a[index]==-1` is being true, with `index` in bounds (that is for sure)

Answer (score 0):

You're forcing a cast from boolean to integer which is not necessary in that case. I would simply use logical operators do implement that same code.

Anyway, answering your question, it can be true.

```
int main(){
    bool a = -1;
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out "a = 1".

Comment: how does that make `a[index]==-1` true ? if -1 is casted to `bool` then i think it could turn out to be true, but then my TEST if condition should print `its true`, so probably its `a[index]` being casted to `int` .. ?

Comment: Yup, i was wrong after all. Only if -1 is casted to bool will it return bool.

Comment: @Phoenix and ecc: The past tense and past participle of cast is cast, not casted :)

Comment: Thanks :P I didn't knew that.